# Show tooltip without series symbols

Tags: echarts

I have a line chart with a rather large set of items in it and I was wondering if there was a way to trigger the tooltip without having symbols on the lines.
I tried using both triggers (axis,item) but no luck.

It looks a bit weird when symbols (i.e. circles) are displayed which is why I want to hide them.

Has anyone had any similar issues?

Thanks

Comment: An correct answer was posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72656104/2763996

Answer (score 1):

How about set `series.symbolSize` to `0` and 'axis' as trigger like below, is this you want?

```js
let echartsObj = echarts.init(document.querySelector('#canvas'));
 
option = {
    tooltip: {
        show: true,
        trigger: 'axis'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
 
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line',
        symbolSize: 0
    }]
};



    echartsObj.setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
      <header>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/echarts/4.1.0.rc2/echarts-en.min.js"></script>
      </header>
      <body>
        <div id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 300px">
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Tried without succeess. Only symbolSize: 1 works, symbolSize: 0 doesn't work